# How to use TerraForm to create pipeline that deploys lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a pipeline using terraform to create a codepipeline in aws to automatically deploy a lambda function.
i have already created 2 stages to get the code from github and build the artifact using codebuild and store the artifact to S3.

But i can't seem to find a terraform configuration for the codedeploy to deploy the artifact from s3 to lambda. I do see there is deployment setting from the console where i can specify the detail of the deployment.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Terraform code you've written and then explain exactly how it doesn't do what you want and where you're struggling? If it throws an error then it would also be helpful to include that in the question too.